# Display payment list in drop-down on checkout page in Magento 2

Tags: magento2, customization, checkout, magento-2.3, payment-method

I am working on customization of checkout page in Magento 2.

My Magento version is 2.3.2

Currently I am stuck at display payment methods list in Magento 2.

Here is what displaying currently.

[image]

Here is what I want to achieve.

[image]

**Note:**
I have overridden below file for checkout page customization in my module.

*vendor/magento/module-checkout/view/frontend/layout/checkout_index_index.xml*

Let me know your suggestion and solutions.
Thanks.

Comment: can you tell if user select new card what will show?

Comment: New card will display form for card details like card number, expire date and authentication code.

Comment: I think you have to override this file vendor/magento/module-checkout/view/frontend/web/template/payment-methods/list.phtml

Comment: check this,
[option instead of radio button](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34899148/11917074)